# Can the camel mongo component connect to a password protected MongoDB instance?

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

My target mongodb database is password protected.

I am trying to connect to it via camel, using the [camel mongodb component](http://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html)

Based on the [code I see](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/camel/trunk/components/camel-mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/mongodb/MongoDbProducer.java?view=markup), I'm not sure camel can take authentication into account. Is this true?

Using Camel 2.11.0, tried both Mongo Java Driver 2.11.1 and 2.9.1.

**My Relevant Code:**

Route:

```
from( "direct:input" )
  .to(mongodb:myDB?database=aDB&collection=aColl&operation=save&writeConcern=SAFE" ))
```

AppCtx:

```
<bean id="myDB" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
<constructor-arg index="0">
    <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoURI">
        <constructor-arg index="0" 
        value="mongodb://$mongodb{user}:$mongodb{passwd}@$mongodb{host}:$mongodb{port}/$mongodb{db}">
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.CamelMongoDbException: 
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { 
 "serverUsed" : "redacted" , 
 "errmsg" : "need to login" , 
 "ok" : 0.0}
```

I'd hate for this to be yet another case where I can't use the component because it just isn't quite there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know camel, so I can't test or validate this, are you passing the value as `value="mongodb://username:password@host:port/db"`?

Comment: Yes, the proper values (which I validated using regular MongoClient calls) are substituted via properties at runtime. Specifically using org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer